# Unable to resolve $proc_date from the script

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

I have multiple HQL's, below is the one example.

located at : **/home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/**

```
insert into XYZ.exttbl_form_data PARTITION (load_date="$proc_date") select FORM_DATA_ID,FORM_ID,USER_ID,INTERACTIONS_ID,SUBMISSION_DATETIME,FILEDS from PQR.exttbl_form_data where load_date="$proc_date"
```

In the main script im reading above mentioned HQLs as

```
export proc_date=2018-05-07

while read line
do
export hql=`cat /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/$table_name.hql`

export hql_final=$(`eval echo"$hql"`)
echo "Final HQL: $hql_final"
hive -e "$hql_final;"

done < /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/config/tables.txt
```

where in tables.txt has list of all HQL.

I want to resolve the $proc_date however that not happening.

Comment: Where are you using your `$line` value?

Comment: 1) in export hql=`cat /home/ganesh/CopyJobs/hql/$table_name.hql` $table_name.hql in undefined. 2) cat will not replace $proc_date's value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure $(`eval echo"$hql"`) is a good choice.

- add a space between `echo` and `"$hql"`
- there are no less than four substitution here, I would have use 3 lines.

I would template `hql` file, e.g. replace `load_date="$proc_date"` by `LOAD_DATA_TMPL`

then, inside the loop

```
hql_final=$(sed s:LOAD_DATA_TMPL:load_date="$proc_date":g /home/ganesh/...)
echo "Final HQL: $hql_final"
hive -e "$hql_final;"
```

- be sure there is no space in `$proc_date`